# Error on saving site template in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, site-template

I have strange and unclear error when I try to save the Site Template.

This is basically the error I get:

> Solution Deployment : Looking for 'ReceiverAssembly' attribute in
>   manifest root node for solution wsp. Solution Deployment : Looking for
>   'ReceiverClass' attribute in manifest root node for solution wsp.
>   SharePoint Solution Deployment : Missing one or more of the following
>   attributes from the root node in solution wsp: assembly '', type ''.
>   Deleting temporary directory
>   C:\Users\TEMP\AppData\Local\Temp\solution-26....

Any idea what this could be and or how can I find out what is causing this? Because on this logging is not that much of help.

I would really appreaciate it.

PS: I have some idea, that this could be a site column or something but i'm not sure ...

Comment: Do you have any custom solution deplouyed to this site collection or web app? looks like a solution giving the error...check the uls log for more info... also try to deactivate / remove the solution from site and then try it

Comment: Yes, of course i have solutions deployed and used in the site. But do you know how can I know which one exactly is causing this? In the logs there is nothing more :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation I found the issue. The issue was that one of the fields had a attribute which was not supported. After deleting this attribute the issue was gone and I could save all my templates.